# jcarousel images disappear after scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an autocomplete text input that triggers a slider using jcarousel to scroll to the image of the selected person.  The problem is, if you search once, it works, but searching again makes all the images disappear.

Here is the code that controls the input:

```
jQuery('#team_select2').change(function() {

    var idx = $('#team_select2').val();

    if(idx == '')
    {
        carousel.scroll(1);
        $('.details').hide();
        return false;
    }

    carousel.scroll(idx);
    $('.details').hide();
    $('#'+idx+'_details').show();
});
```

You can see it breaking in action if you go to http://welchhornsby.com/new-team-page/ and try searching for two of the people in the list.

Anyone have any idea why it would be breaking like that?

Comment: First, I don't see that behavior in firefox, but it also doesn't work as you described.  Looking at the generated HTML, I don't see any `id` attributes on the `li` or the `img`.  Do they appear properly in your browser?

Comment: Found the answer right after posting this.  Just changed the 4th to last row from carousel.scroll(idx); to carousel.scroll(idx*1);

Comment: Isn't `id*1` === `idx`?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer right after posting this. Just changed the 4th to last row from `carousel.scroll(idx);` to `carousel.scroll(idx*1);`

Comment: You might consider elaborating as to what the actual problem was and why this fixed the problem, that way someone else who has a similar problem in the future has something useful to draw on.

Comment: Thanks so much for posting this answer! Was the tip I needed